# How to move to a folder and execute a Windows command line call

Tags: c++, windows

This is simple to do in languages like Python, but I'm not sure how to do it in C++.  I want to move to a specific folder, say "C:\tests" and run some command line call from that folder.  Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can start a process in a specific directory using the [`CreateProcess()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682425%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) call.  In particular, look at the `lpCurrentDirectory` argument:

> **lpCurrentDirectory** [in, optional]
>
> The full path to the current directory for the process. The string can also specify
>   a UNC path.  If this parameter is NULL, the new process will have the same current drive
>   and directory as the calling process. (This feature is provided primarily for shells that
>   need to start an application and specify its initial drive and working directory.)

This function is used internally by Python's [`subprocess.Popen`'s constructor](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html#popen-constructor).

Answer (score 0):

You want [`SetCurrentDirectory`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365530%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for changing directories and `system` for executing a command asynchronously.  `system` is the simple way to do it.  You can use [`CreateProcess`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682425%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) if you need flexibility.

Answer (score 0):

Create a bat file and put cd command there to set required path and then write your command to execute. Ex in your bat file write
line1 "cd c:/tests/" 
line2 "your command to be executed"
After that you could use system("*.bat") to call your bat file. See more info related to that here http://faq.cprogramming.com/cgi-bin/smartfaq.cgi?answer=1044654269&id=1043284392 Hope this helps

Comment: Having an extra batch file floating around isn't exactly the most elegant way of achieving it...